# Optimizing pages from side of javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization

I need to know about two things. I was looking on google but I could not found any good.

**First thing is: Location of the scripts in the structure of documents.**

Can anyone explain to me what's going on? How it works to optimize pages and where you should put the scripts?

**Second thing is: Packing and compressing js code.**

I find some packers in google like this: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ but how its work? All writen scripts should pack?

Please for an explanation or some link to article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your first point, one answer to look at would be this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/1145461

Concerning the 2nd point, hopefully this link will help:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: Thanks for link. That's just what I was looking for.